# How to find stock i’s benchmark return for Cash-Value Regression

Tags: fama-french, cash

I would appreciate any help or guidance please as I do not understand how to find the corresponding portfolio to use as benchmark to find the Excess Return that is used in the Baseline Regression model of Faulkender & Wang (2006). My doubt is with the dependent variable:

$$
r_{i,t}-R^{B}_{i,t} = \text{independent variables} + \epsilon_{i,t}
$$

Where:
$$r_{i,t}$$ is stock return during year t
and
$$R^{B}_{i,t}$$
is the benchmark portfolio return at year t.

Where they explain:

> "To arrive at our estimate of the excess return, we use the 25 Fama and French portfolios formed on size and book-to-market as our benchmark portfolios. A portfolio return is a value-weighted return based on market capitalization within each of the 25 portfolios. For each year, we group every firm into one of 25 size and BE/ME portfolios based on the intersection between the size and book-to-market independent sorts. Fama and French (1993) conclude that size and the book-to-market of equity proxy for sensitivity to common risk factors in stock returns, which implies that stocks in different size and book-to-market portfolios may have different expected returns. Therefore, stock i’s benchmark return at year t is the return of the portfolio to which stock i belongs at the beginning of fiscal year t. To form a size- and BE/ME-excess return for any stock, we simply subtract the return of the portfolio to which it belongs from the realized return of the stock." (p.1967)

- I have downloaded the different files from Fama and French needed, but I do not understand how to know which of the 25 portfolios should I select to calculate the excess return.
- I have the returns for each of the companies I need.

Thanks in advance, and if this is not the place to post, I would thank you for any help. Best.

- Reference: Faulkender, M., & Wang, R. (2006). Corporate financial policy and the value of cash. The Journal of Finance, 61(4), 1957-1990. [Link](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2006.00894.x)